# Everything In CRM is Slow - Errors With CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache

Tags: mysql, cache

After a database was corrupted and reloaded from a backup. 
Looking at the error log this appears to be where CiviCRM is hanging.

> CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::load(Object(CRM_Core_DAO))

Here is the debug information.

> [debug_info] => CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
>   civicrm_temp_group_contact_cache1632  (SELECT 95 as group_id, 
>   contact_a.id as id   FROM civicrm_contact contact_a    LEFT JOIN
>   civicrm_email ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_email.contact_id AND
>   civicrm_email.is_primary = 1)   WHERE  (  ( 
>   (NULLIF(civicrm_email.email, '') IS NOT NULL)  AND
>   contact_a.do_not_email =  AND contact_a.is_opt_out =  AND
>   contact_a.contact_type = 'Individual' )  )  AND (contact_a.is_deleted
>   = 0)   AND contact_a.id NOT IN (
>                                  SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_group_contact
>                                  WHERE civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Removed'
>                                 AND   civicrm_group_contact.group_id = 95 ) ); [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'AND contact_a.is_opt_out =  AND
>   contact_a.contact_type = 'Individual' )  )  AND ' at line 1]

Any advice on how to resolve this is appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 2):

There's something wrong with your smart group with an ID of 95.  However, this is unlikely to be causing a performance problem, since this query simply isn't running.  If you can delete and recreate your smart group with an ID of 95, this error should go away.